# Celery python synchronous tasks

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

In my application, I have python celery tasks that connect to a rest API..  simple.

The problem I have is that the API does not allow multiple resuests with the same credentials.

Is there a way to have these api tasks blocking in the queue?  Meaning, If multiple requests are made around the same time, can I have the tasks sit in the queue and execute one by one, waiting for the first in the queue to finish?

Currently, in the rabbitmq message queue (with one worker), i see the tasks go through (spawned) and not wait.

I looked over documentation but could not find a simple solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With one worker it's impossible for celery to do more than one task at a time. what you may be seeing is called prefetching which allows the worker to reserve tasks.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#prefetch-limits

The default prefetch value is 4, turn it down to one and see if that fixes it.